# How to add post response string of dictionary values to label while parsing in swift

Tags: json, swift, string, dictionary, post

json post response like this:

```
     {
"response": {
    "responseReason": "Successful",
    "billDetails": "",
    "billerResponse":"{\"customerName\":\"RAM\",\"amount\":193,\"dueDate\":\"2019-11-30\",\"custConvFee\":\"\",\"custConvDesc\":\"\",\"billDate\":\"2019-11-16\",\"billNumber\":\"32224081911191623\",\"billPeriod\":\"NA\",\"billTags\":[],\"fieldName\":\"Service Number\",\"fieldValue\":\"116515M025007621\",\"billerName\":\"EPDCL-Eastern Power Distribution Ltd\"}",
```

for that i have written code like this:
here i am getting json response but i need `customerName` `amount`  `dueDate` values in label

```
func billerFetchService(){    

let parameters = ["billDetails": [
    "billerId" : "EPDCLOB00ANP01",
    "customerParams" : [["name":"Service Number","value":"116515M025007621"]]]]

let url = URL(string: "https://app.com/fetch_v1/fetch")
var req =  URLRequest(url: url!)
req.httpMethod = "POST"
req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Contet-Type")
req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) else {return}
req.httpBody = httpBody
let session = URLSession.shared
session.dataTask(with: req, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    if response != nil {
        // print(response)
    }
    if let data = data {
        do{
            var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
             print("fetching json \(json)")

            let billerDetails = json["billerResponse"] as! String
            print("fetch only billerdetails \(billerDetails)")

            let res = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:Data(billerDetails.utf8)) as! [String: Any]
            let billerName = res["customerName"] as? String
            print("fetch only EPDCL biller name \(billerName)"

        }catch{
            print("error")
        }
    }
}).resume()
}
```

`let billerDetails = json["billerResponse"] as! String` here i am getting

> Thread 5: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
let billerDetails = json["response"] as! [String:Any]
let value = billerDetails["billerResponse"] as! String
print(value)
```

Comment: please help me here , i got stuck here from long time .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959492/how-to-send-json-dictionary-key-value-to-next-view-controller-array-in-swift